# slicing to reverse string confusion

Tags: python

This has been asked many times but i do not want to ask that again . I just want to know how
is this happening ?

```
>>> st="arindam"

>>> st[::-1]   #This is the one that everyone probably uses 
'madnira'
```

Would someone please explain why this works?

```
>>> st[-1::-1]
'madnira'
```

How is this also reversing the string successfully? I thought this would start from 'a'
and print 'adnira'

Comment: Index -1 is the last character of the string, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python list indexes, the index `-1` refers to the *last* character in the string. When using a negative step index, omitting the start index uses `-1` as the start (a positive step index starts at `0` by default).

Comment: Ah.........That explains it......Thank you Sir

Comment: I think that would make `start:end:step` act just like `range(start,end,step)`?

Answer (score 1):

because st[-1] is 'm':

```
>>> st="arindam"
>>> st[-1]
'm'
>>> st[::-1]
'madnira'
>>> st[-1::-1]
'madnira'
>>> st[-2::-1]
'adnira'
```

Comment: `>>> st[-1:0:-1]`
`'madnir'`

But `>>> st[-1::-1]`
`'madnira'`

How did this happen?

Comment: 0 and None (which is implied between '::') behave differently.